# AWS - Invoke common task Lambda for each API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

We have a requirement to write custom logs for the application to capture the things like who did what and when.

To do that we have created a Lambda to insert the logs in DynamoDb database. We need this Lambda to be called from a common place every time we call an API from frontend of the application instead of invoking it in each and every individual lambdas.

We tried invoking this in the API Gateway Authorizer but it doesn't work because our gateway authorizer is of type 'Token'. So, it does not accept any other parameters than access token. We cannot change the type of custom authorizer to type 'Request' because we need access token to be present for authorizing user in Cognito.
Question:
Is there any place where we can invoke this Logs Lambda so that it executes when each API is called?

Comment: What about using CloudFront in front of your Api gateway? In cloudfront you have lambda@edge which could be executed for every request.

Answer (score 0):

Your last paragraph makes no sense but typically the best way to do this is streaming, as this minimises the amount of Lambda invocations you need to make.

You can stream API Access logs which contain things like the path, current time, principal to a cloudwatch log streams, or a lambda.

In this lambda you can do your custom logging logic there. If you have other sources which will have different types of events you may need to use Kinesis directly for streaming.

Answer (score 0):

try using a different event trigger. If your lambda can get triggered by a queue or cloudfront you won't have authorization problems. however your application has to assume a suitable role to use some of these. If you're using Java, you can intercept your request in many ways and make the lambda call via SDK before processing the API. Need more details to provide a holistic solution.